# reactjs and node js npm not woking

Tags: node.js, reactjs

My npm start is not working while I am running my project in command prompt. I am getting  below error

> at new Script (vm.js:51:7) at createScript (vm.js:138:10) at
>   Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10) at Module._compile
>   (module.js:624:28) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>   at Module.load (module.js:573:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3) at Module.require
>   (module.js:604:17) at require (internal/module.js:11:18) npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! react_basics@1.0.0 build:
>   webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && wepack-dev-server
>   --content-base src/ --inline --hot` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the react_basics@1.0.0 build script. npm ERR! This
>   is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\shiva\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-02-10T16_52_04_130Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! react_basics@1.0.0
>   start: npm run build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
>   at the react_basics@1.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not
>   a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\shiva\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-02-10T16_52_04_208Z-debug.log

Comment: Better formated questions, get better answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed dependencies? Try running first `npm install` and then `npm start`